# Python Flask SQLite3 - problems with routing and database

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite, routes

I am having problems with routing to a webpage after checking the username and password and if I enter a long username and password it says: "list index out of range". In my database there is only one user (admin user which I have created manually). I am trying to only work on that and after it works I will be working on the registration.

This is the code that forwards to the login page:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

This is the code that checks the login credentials:

```
@app.route('/logincheck', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logincheck():
    error = None
    checkP = g.db.execute('select pword from users where uname = ?', (request.form['username'], ))
    arrayCheck = checkP.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['password'] != arrayCheck[[0][0]]:
            error = 'Username or password is incorrect'
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        if len(arrayCheck) == 0:
            error = 'Username or password is incorrect'
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You are logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('userpage'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

In the html file "login.html" I have a form that forwards to /logincheck and logincheck forwards to userpage which is the website itself.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @MrLeeh If I enter the admin credentials it doesn't forward me to /logincheck and if I enter any other username and password it does the list index problem.

Comment: So what is the error message when you enter admin credentials?

Comment: @metmirr Nothing, it just doesn't forward me to the page I want. It forwards me back to the login page instead of userpage.

Comment: if you are seeing flashed message `You are logged in` then the question is do you have a view function named `userpage`

Comment: @metmirr I don't see anything flashing. As I said, it redirects me back to the login page instead of userpage. The userpage.html is just an empty html page, to check if it works. I made an app.route to the userpage but it still doesn't work

Comment: it means one of your two `if` blocks word not `else` change this one `error = 'Username or password is incorrect'` to `flash('Username or password is incorrect')` in both `if` statement to see where is the error

Comment: @metmirr It says that I have an error with this: if request.form['password'] != arrayCheck[[0][0]]:. I don't know why.

Comment: `print(arrayCheck[[0][0]])` show us output

Comment: @metmirr My username is tom and password is sim. This is what it printed: (u'sim',)

Comment: @metmirr I figured out the problem. If I print what I write it says: "sim". In the database, if I print it, it prints: (u'sim',). I just have to extract it now.

Comment: yes because `(u'sim',)` is a tuple and `sim` is just a string